# Pass a function with parameter as an argument to another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I am a beginner. I am trying to do something like this -

```js
function write(x, y, z) {
  x();
  console.log("This is foo: ", y, z);
}
var b = 32,
  c = 92;
function a(d) {
  console.log("This is d from a:", d);
  return d;
}
write(a(12), b, c);
```

And I am getting an Error below -

```
caspio-common.js:73 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (caspio-common.js:73:26)
at f_dataPageReadyEvent.dispatchEvent (<anonymous>:1:523)
at f_dataPageReadyEvent.init (<anonymous>:1:91)
at new <anonymous> (<anonymous>:2:34)
at <anonymous>:1:1
at f_dpLoadObj.addScriptElement (...
```

My question is how can I run x(x) with parameter inside write function.

Thank you

Comment: You can't run x because it's not a function

Comment: `a.bind( null, 12)`

Comment: `write(() => a(12), b, c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this

```
function pass1(value){
  return ("Hello " + value);
}

function pass2(){
  return (" Howdy!");
}

function receive_pass(func1, func2){
  console.log(func1("world!")+func2());
}

receive_pass(pass1, pass2);
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `x` because you did not pass the function itself but the returned value of a function as the parameter.

```
write(a(12), b, c);
// a(12) -> returns 12 which is not a function and thus not callable
```

One solution to make this work is wrapping the function call into another function.

```
write(function() {
    a(12);
}, b, c);
```

Or use this commonly used syntax.

```
write(() => a(12), b, c);
```

---

Full working example

```js
function write(x, y, z) {
  x();
  console.log("This is foo: ", y, z);
}

var b = 32,
  c = 92;

function a(d) {
  console.log("This is d from a:", d);
  return d;
}

write(() => a(12), b, c);
```